# Column isn't added to dataframe but also there is no error message

Tags: r, dataframe, padding

I've got a dataframe in RStudio and I'm trying to add a new column based on another column. It should basically copy the value from the other column but pad it to the left with character `a` to max length of 12 characters.

Here is my code.

```
# test dataframe
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",", text = "patcode,atccode
1001,b01ab06
2002,a02bc02
3003,b03bb01
4004,g03aa07
5005,j01ca04")

# add new column, atccode padded with 'a' max 12x
df$test_123 <- ifelse(nchar(df$atccode) < 12,
                      paste(c(rep("a",12-nchar(df$atccode)), df$atccode), collapse=""),
                      df$atccode)
```

The expected result is that the dataframe `df` should now have 3 columns, so with a new `test_123` column which is a copy of `atccode` padded with "a" to max of 12 characters.

But instead, the dataframe is unchanged and I get no error message. What am I doing wrong? Is there a typo that I'm missing? And if so, why do I not get an error message?

(btw it is a relatively simple operation, and due to other requirements it should preferably only use base R)

Comment: I get the error message "Error in rep("a", 12 - nchar(df$atccode)) : invalid 'times' argument". Because you're passing a vector as a second argument.
Try in a console.
Do you see an error if you run `stopifnot(F)`?

Comment: `stringr::str_pad()` would also most likely provide a simpler solution.

Comment: @Ric it's odd I after a complete restart of my laptop I now do also get the same error message in the console. But I swear I wasn't getting it before. I had Rstudio opened on my desktop for a couple of days and using it on and off but without ever closing it.

Comment: Yes, better to restart it sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to create a function as it allows for values of varying lengths (I manually amended the "atcode" value on row 5 to test).

This answer is adapted from one on the thread at [r padding strings to same length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134110/r-padding-strings-to-same-length).

```r
    # add new column, atccode padded with 'a' max 12x
    # create function
    pad_strings <- function(char_vec, max_len=12, pad="a") {
      reps <- Vectorize(function(n) paste(rep(pad, n), collapse=""))
      lengths <- nchar(char_vec)
      if (is.null(max_len)) max_len <- max(lengths)
      diffs <- max_len - lengths
      paste0(reps(diffs), char_vec)
    }
    
    #apply function to new column
    df$test_123 <- pad_strings(df$atccode)
```

Results in the following:

head(df)

|  | patcode | atccode | test_123 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | b01ab06 | aaaaab01ab06 |
| 2 | 2002 | a02bc02 | aaaaaa02bc02 |
| 3 | 3003 | b03bb01 | aaaaab03bb01 |
| 4 | 4004 | g03aa07 | aaaaag03aa07 |
| 5 | 5005 | xj01ca04 | aaaaxj01ca04 |

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in the comments, `stringr::str_pad()` makes this easier:

```r
library(stringr)

df$test_123 <- stringr::str_pad(df$atccode,  max(nchar(df$atccode)), pad = "a")

df
#>   patcode        atccode       test_123
#> 1    1001 b01ab06b01ab06 b01ab06b01ab06
#> 2    2002    a02bc024349 aaaa02bc024349
#> 3    3003      b03bb01de aaaaab03bb01de
#> 4    4004        g03aa07 aaaaaaag03aa07
#> 5    5005          j01c4 aaaaaaaaaj01c4
```

Advanced test data:

```r
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",", text = "patcode,atccode
1001,b01ab06b01ab06
2002,a02bc024349
3003,b03bb01de
4004,g03aa07
5005,j01c4")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand why you need to use a `max()`. I mean at the start of the ifelse statement, why doesn't the `nchar(df$atccode) < 12` part need a max()?

Comment: Wait I just realised, this doesn't work. When the column contains data with different lengths, then they are all just padded with the same amount of `a` characters. Sorry, I didn't specify this in the example, but the real data sometimes contains values with fewer or more than 7 characters.

Comment: @BdR: I now updated the example with some advanced test data and only used `str_pad` which makes this really easy. Inside `str_pad` we can use `max(nchar(df$atccode)` to get the maxium number of characters used and pad all other values accordingly.